# I want this custom button to be placed just below the short product description or beside add to cart button. Help me

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added this function to functions.php and the code is all fine but it's just that the placement is not good, I want the custom button to be placed just below or in place of the short product description area which is basically just below the price tag, and I tried placing it just beside the "Add to Cart" button but it's going to close to each other and I need bit space between them if anyone has a solution for putting it beside the add to cart button but a little bit of space and must be responsive.

Can anyone in my beloved community will help me out, I'm all stuck, I'm trying with a hook but not giving the desired location for the button which I want... You guys can give me direct hooks for my desired location or do any extra CSS needs to be added? I'm clueless here.

Here's my code:

```
// Enqueue necessary scripts for media uploader
function enqueue_media_uploader_scripts($hook) {
    if ($hook === 'post.php' || $hook === 'post-new.php') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_media_uploader_scripts');

// Modify meta box to use media uploader
function modify_pdf_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'pdf_meta_box',
        'PDF File',
        'render_pdf_meta_box',
        'product',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'modify_pdf_meta_box');

// Render PDF meta box HTML with media uploader
function render_pdf_meta_box($post) {
    $pdf_file_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pdf_file', true);
    $pdf_file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($pdf_file_id);

    echo '<p><label for="pdf_file">PDF File:</label><br />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pdf_file" name="pdf_file" value="' . $pdf_file_id . '" />';
    echo '<input type="button" id="upload_pdf_button" class="button alt" value="تحميل الداتا شيت" /></p>';
    echo '<p>Current PDF: <a href="' . $pdf_file_url . '" target="_blank">' . $pdf_file_url . '</a></p>';
}

// Save PDF file information
function save_pdf_file_info($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['pdf_file']) && !empty($_POST['pdf_file'])) {
        $pdf_file_id = intval($_POST['pdf_file']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_pdf_file', $pdf_file_id);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_pdf_file_info');

// Add custom button to WooCommerce single product page
function add_custom_button_to_product_page() {
    global $product;

    $pdf_file_id = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_pdf_file', true);
    $pdf_file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($pdf_file_id);

    if (!empty($pdf_file_url)) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($pdf_file_url) . '" target="blank" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">' . _('تحميل الداتا شيت', 'text-domain') . '</a>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_button_to_product_page', -1);

// Add custom script for media uploader
function custom_media_uploader_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var file_frame;
            $('#upload_pdf_button').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (file_frame) {
                    file_frame.open();
                    return;
                }

                file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: 'Select PDF File',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Use this PDF',
                    },
                    multiple: false
                });

                file_frame.on('select', function() {
                    var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    $('#pdf_file').val(attachment.id);
                });

                file_frame.open();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_media_uploader_script');
```

I'm giving a screenshot of the single product page for better understanding.

[image: For Visual Understanding]

Note this is for WooCommerce.

Any solution for both locations?

For better understanding, I'm giving this screenshot also for the location.